# Create new file in Linux directory with names of files in that directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have directory in `Linux` called `test`. `test` directory has `123.txt`, `456.txt` files in it.

Now I want to create a new file that has the names of files in `test` directory.

Requirement:

In `test` directory A new file called `lines.txt`.

The contents of `lines.txt` file are below

```
123.txt
456.txt
```

I have tried like below

```
ls > lines.txt
```

`Output`

```
123.txt
456.txt
lines.txt
```

How can I achieve what my requirement.

Comment: So you want to exclude "lines.txt" from showing up in lines.txt?

Comment: @logix yes that is what I want

Comment: `| fgrep -v -x lines.txt` ?

Comment: Or, assuming you don't want to list hidden files, `> .hidden.txt && mv .hidden.txt lines.txt`

Comment: kudos to @o11c for use of `-x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
ls | fgrep -v -x lines.txt > lines.txt
```

This should work in your case.

It filters out the new file names and redirects to new file

Answer (score 1):

Since the file gets created before `ls` is run, you'll need to work around it.

You can use `tee`:

`ls |tee lines.txt`

Or filter out the name using grep:

`ls |grep -v lines.txt > lines.txt`

Comment: Piping to `tee` is racy, it usually won't help.

Comment: @logix `ls |tee lines.txt` didn't work but the other did work